# Can't resolve all names once connected to a VPN

Tags: linux, dns, raspbian, openvpn, vpn

I had some trouble to establish a connection with a VPN server. Here is a link to the concerned thread: [StackExchange VPN connection](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/344493/establish-a-connection-with-openvpn-on-raspbian).

It was mainly a DNS issue and it works now. However, I can now resolve some names, but not all of them. I can resolve `www.google.com`, but not `torrent.ubuntu.com` for example. Even if I use the command `dig` to specify the DNS I want to use, I can't resolve `torrent.ubuntu.com` while connected to the VPN. When I'm not connected to the VPN, I can resolve it, and I can also resolve it by using the DNS of my VPN server.

Not connected to VPN (84.200.69.80 is the DNS address given by my VPN server):

```
pi@raspberrypi:/etc/openvpn/vpnbook $ dig torrent.ubuntu.com

; <<>> DiG 9.9.5-9+deb8u10-Raspbian <<>> torrent.ubuntu.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 12612
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 512
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;torrent.ubuntu.com.            IN      A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
torrent.ubuntu.com.     600     IN      A       91.189.95.21

;; Query time: 26 msec
;; SERVER: 194.168.4.100#53(194.168.4.100)
;; WHEN: Tue Mar 28 23:36:14 UTC 2017
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 63



pi@raspberrypi:/etc/openvpn/vpnbook $ dig @8.8.8.8 torrent.ubuntu.com

; <<>> DiG 9.9.5-9+deb8u10-Raspbian <<>> @8.8.8.8 torrent.ubuntu.com
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 54658
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 512
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;torrent.ubuntu.com.            IN      A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
torrent.ubuntu.com.     565     IN      A       91.189.95.21

;; Query time: 38 msec
;; SERVER: 8.8.8.8#53(8.8.8.8)
;; WHEN: Tue Mar 28 23:36:30 UTC 2017
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 63



pi@raspberrypi:/etc/openvpn/vpnbook $ dig @84.200.69.80 torrent.ubuntu.com

; <<>> DiG 9.9.5-9+deb8u10-Raspbian <<>> @84.200.69.80 torrent.ubuntu.com
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 25789
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 4, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;torrent.ubuntu.com.            IN      A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
torrent.ubuntu.com.     153     IN      A       91.189.95.21

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
ubuntu.com.             600     IN      NS      ns4.p27.dynect.net.
ubuntu.com.             600     IN      NS      ns2.p27.dynect.net.
ubuntu.com.             600     IN      NS      ns1.p27.dynect.net.
ubuntu.com.             600     IN      NS      ns3.p27.dynect.net.

;; Query time: 48 msec
;; SERVER: 84.200.69.80#53(84.200.69.80)
;; WHEN: Tue Mar 28 23:36:47 UTC 2017
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 149
```

Connected to the VPN:

```
pi@raspberrypi:/etc/openvpn/vpnbook $ dig torrent.ubuntu.com

; <<>> DiG 9.9.5-9+deb8u10-Raspbian <<>> torrent.ubuntu.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached



pi@raspberrypi:/etc/openvpn/vpnbook $ dig @84.200.69.80 torrent.ubuntu.com

; <<>> DiG 9.9.5-9+deb8u10-Raspbian <<>> @84.200.69.80 torrent.ubuntu.com
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached



pi@raspberrypi:/etc/openvpn/vpnbook $ dig @8.8.8.8 torrent.ubuntu.com

; <<>> DiG 9.9.5-9+deb8u10-Raspbian <<>> @8.8.8.8 torrent.ubuntu.com
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached



pi@raspberrypi:/etc/openvpn/vpnbook $ dig www.google.com

; <<>> DiG 9.9.5-9+deb8u10-Raspbian <<>> www.google.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 59828
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;www.google.com.                        IN      A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
www.google.com.         132     IN      A       172.217.20.196

;; Query time: 211 msec
;; SERVER: 84.200.69.80#53(84.200.69.80)
;; WHEN: Tue Mar 28 23:38:58 UTC 2017
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 59
```

Comment: Can you reach the servers via the VPN? What does `ping` or `mtr -t` for `84.200.69.80` and `8.8.8.8` say? Maybe your VPN is blocking usage of other DNS servers besides its own?

Comment: Yes I can reach the servers via the VPN. www.google.com is resolved using the DNS provided by the VPN server. Do you think the VPN server can block only some DNS requests? With the word torrent in it for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After surfing a bit on internet, it seems pretty obvious that the VPN server is blocking every DNS request which contains the word "torrent", even if it's a legal torrent like `torrent.ubuntu.com`.